# Different results from one rmd flexdasboard file

Tags: r, dt, flexdashboard

i made an html flexdasboard to make an overview about Documents. When i Knit my rmd file everything works perfect. When someone else use my rmd file he gets the same resuts but his Datatable dont fit into the whole html screen. The zoom of the browser is the same. Why is that happening.

Thats the result of my colleague.

[image]

And that is my result.

[image]

And thats the basic code i use:

[image]

Thanks for the help.